# Sockets. Programming chat room in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to make a simple chat room in Python 3.0. I made 2 files called **client.py** and **server.py**

Thats how server looks like:

```
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8123))

serversocket.listen()

def server(clientsocket):
    rd= clientsocket.recv(512)
    clientsocket.send(b'Hello' +rd)
    data= str(rd)
    print('sending:' +str(data))
    print('from connected user:' +str(data))
   if not data:
       break
   else:
    clientsocket.close

while True:

    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print("New connection from: %s:%d" % address)

    conn = socket
    rd = clientsocket.recv(512)


serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
serversocket.listen()



    conn.send(data.encode())


    if output.strip()=="disconnected":
        conn.close()
```

In this code, I'm having 3 bugs. First is "if not data: break. I'm getting `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. I don't know what that really means.

Then there is `conn.send(data.encode())` on the bottom. I'm getting an error which looks like this: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

And the last error is `if output.strip()=="disconnected":`. `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

My **client.py** file looks like this:

```
import socket


clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8123))

message= input('New message')

while message!='q':
    clientsocket.send(message.encode())
    data = clientsocket.recv(512).decode()

    print('New message from:' + data)

    message = input("New message")
clientsocket.close()



payload =  input()
clientsocket.payload.endode("UTF-8")
clientsocket.send(payload).decode()
print("Sends: " + payload)
reply = clientsocket.recv(512)
print("Received: " + reply)
```

Client.py works as it should, but I have a problem to print a name of a person who wrote a message. I hope you know what I mean.

My last problem is that my server doesn't have any loop so after 2 messages my program crashes.

I'm new to programming and sorry if I did anything wrong. I'm new into programming and StackOverflow and I hope you will help me with my code.

Answer (score 0):

All those error on **server.py** are because you didn't **indent** your code properly. (as the error tells you).

In Python you have to respect the number of space at the start of the line to get the code to properly get executed.

Here your

```
   if not data:
       break
```

has 3 spaces before it instead of 4, that's why you get the error.

Then

```
    conn.send(data.encode())


    if output.strip()=="disconnected":
        conn.close()
```

are indented when they shouldn't. Remove the space before it, (or indent properly the code before those line if it is what the code is supposed to do).

Comment: It really doesn't help if I'm using 3 or 4 spaces in "if not data". I'm getting now "break outside loop". I want also to say thank you for helping me

Comment: you have to put an extra space before the  "break" too, and another before the "else", and "clientsocket.close"